tmux plugins defined with nix cause 127 errors
Overview
I'm trying to setup tmux using nix and home-manager on macOS.
However whenever I refresh the tmux config, I get the following errors:
'/nix/store/6iq9z3wnacxqhja3r93b7lsdl1kvcp11-tmuxplugin-sensible-unstable-2017-09-05/share/tmux-plugins/sensible/sensible.tmux' returned 127                                                                                                                            [0/0]
'/nix/store/6iq9z3wnacxqhja3r93b7lsdl1kvcp11-tmuxplugin-sensible-unstable-2017-09-05/share/tmux-plugins/sensible/sensible.tmux' returned 127
'/nix/store/8cqfwlqfxp21fwbcvl8dyyahdm4klmxj-tmuxplugin-catppuccin-unstable-2024-05-15/share/tmux-plugins/catppuccin/catppuccin.tmux' returned 127
'/nix/store/87czlf8i2q2bzk1xikhx20d80g9kpdi9-tmuxplugin-resurrect-unstable-2022-05-01/share/tmux-plugins/resurrect/resurrect.tmux' returned 127
'/nix/store/aqs7gq94wd4ldbbsnrrm232jifbywwjy-tmuxplugin-continuum-unstable-2022-01-25/share/tmux-plugins/continuum/continuum.tmux' returned 127
'/nix/store/ixmqzdn5yck23fi1d824a04mvxkb7jk6-tmuxplugin-yank-unstable-2021-06-20/share/tmux-plugins/yank/yank.tmux' returned 127

Debugging
I looked at the generated tmux.conf file and found that there's several run-shell commands such as the following:
# ============================================= #
# Start with defaults from the Sensible plugin  #
# --------------------------------------------- #
run-shell /nix/store/6iq9z3wnacxqhja3r93b7lsdl1kvcp11-tmuxplugin-sensible-unstable-2017-09-05/share/tmux-plugins/sensible/sensible.tmux
# ============================================= #

These run-shell commands match the programs with 127 errors in the tmux logs.
According to this GitHub issue, 127 errors means the program was not found. Howevern when I explicitly try running those programs or cat them out, I see them.
So this tells me that for some reason I can manually run the generated programs, but tmux cannot.
I found this post: tmux run fish shell functions returns error 127. So I also tried running the generated .tmux programs using /bin/sh and could successfully run them there.
Files
Here's my entire nix configuration for tmux.
{ pkgs, ... }:
{
  programs.tmux = {
    enable = true;
    terminal = "tmux-256color";
    historyLimit = 100000;
    shell = "${pkgs.zsh}/bin/zsh";
    plugins = with pkgs;
      [
        tmuxPlugins.sensible
        {
          plugin = tmuxPlugins.catppuccin;
          extraConfig = ''
            set-option -sa terminal-features "screen-256color,:RGB"
            set -g @catppuccin_flavour 'mocha'
            set -g @catppuccin_status_modules_right "session"
            set -g @catppuccin_status_modules_left " "
            set -g @catppuccin_status_fill "icon"
            set -g @catppuccin_window_number_position "right"
            set -g @catppuccin_window_left_separator ""
            set -g @catppuccin_window_right_separator " "
            set -g @catppuccin_window_middle_separator " █"
            set -g @catppuccin_window_number_position "right"
            set -g @catppuccin_window_default_fill "none"
            set -g @catppuccin_window_default_text "#W"
            set -g @catppuccin_window_current_fill "number"
            set -g @catppuccin_window_current_text "#W"
            set -g @catppuccin_pane_active_border_style "fg=#313244"
            set -g status-bg "#11111b" # also duplicated at the bottom of the file
          '';
        }
        {
          plugin = tmuxPlugins.resurrect;
          extraConfig = ''
            set -g @resurrect-strategy-nvim 'session'
            set -g @resurrect-capture-pane-contents 'on'
          '';
        }
        {
          plugin = tmuxPlugins.continuum;
          extraConfig = ''
            set -g @continuum-restore 'on'
            set -g @continuum-boot 'on'
            set -g @continuum-boot-options 'alacritty,fullscreen'
            set -g @continuum-save-interval '5' # save every 5 minutes
          '';
        }
        tmuxPlugins.yank
      ];
    extraConfig = ''
      #
      # Keyboard shortcuts
      #

      # set the leader to control-a
      set -g prefix C-a
      unbind C-b
      bind-key C-a send-prefix

      # use \ to create horizontal panes
      unbind %
      bind '\' split-window -h

      # use - to split the window horizontally
      unbind '"'
      bind - split-window -v

      # resize panes
      bind -r j resize-pane -D 5
      bind -r k resize-pane -U 5
      bind -r l resize-pane -R 5
      bind -r h resize-pane -L 5

      # Smart pane switching with awareness of Vim splits.
      # See: https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator
      is_vim="ps -o state= -o comm= -t '#{pane_tty}' \
          | grep -iqE '^[^TXZ ]+ +(\\S+\\/)?g?(view|l?n?vim?x?|fzf)(diff)?$'"
      bind-key -n 'C-h' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-h'  'select-pane -L'
      bind-key -n 'C-j' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-j'  'select-pane -D'
      bind-key -n 'C-k' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-k'  'select-pane -U'
      bind-key -n 'C-l' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-l'  'select-pane -R'
      tmux_version='$(tmux -V | sed -En "s/^tmux ([0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?).*/\1/p")'
      if-shell -b '[ "$(echo "$tmux_version < 3.0" | bc)" = 1 ]' \
          "bind-key -n 'C-\\' if-shell \"$is_vim\" 'send-keys C-\\'  'select-pane -l'"
      if-shell -b '[ "$(echo "$tmux_version >= 3.0" | bc)" = 1 ]' \
          "bind-key -n 'C-\\' if-shell \"$is_vim\" 'send-keys C-\\\\'  'select-pane -l'"

      bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'C-h' select-pane -L
      bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'C-j' select-pane -D
      bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'C-k' select-pane -U
      bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'C-l' select-pane -R
      bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'C-\' select-pane -l

      # set visual styling
      set-option -sa terminal-features "screen-256color,:RGB"
      set-option -g status-position top

      # easily refresh tmux configuration
      unbind r
      bind r source-file ~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf

      set -g status-bg "#11111b"
    '';
  };
}


Because of Yeshwanth's answer, I realized that I could try killing tmux and restarting it.
tmux kill-server

This fixed my problem. No idea why, but turning it off then on again often works.

sounds like an issue with the shell environment that you are using to start the tmux session. if you use other programs like kitty to auto start a tmux session for you, use an interactive login shell to start it. something like
${pkgs.zsh}/bin/zsh -l -i -c "${pkgs.tmux}/bin/tmux new-session -s local-tmux-session"


Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately that's not the case for my setup. I use Alacritty and manually started the session.
